# Get Google account username of the Google Play account from which the app is installed

Tags: android, google-play

In my app, I need to find the email address of the user who installed the app from play store. I can get all the Google accounts present on the device using AccountManager, but can't distinguish from which account the user has installed the app from play store.

Can you tell me and possible way to achieve this?

Comment: AccountManager.get(getActivity()).getAccountsByType("com.google")

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible! If you try something like this, Google will kick you out from store for ever :)